# How to edit .tmux.conf on wsl2 ubuntu?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux

I'm following a tutorial for learning tmux and can't find the .tmux.conf file in ~/.tmux.conf
is there a place i need to go to find it or create the file?
Also I'm running it on wsl2 if that changes anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the `~/.tmux.conf` config yourself. Either, create it from an example file you have, or create one with the default values with this command from within `tmux`:

```
tmux show -g > ~/.tmux.conf
```

Partly inspired by [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294956/how-do-i-get-a-default-tmux-configuration-file).